# Name attribute selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use the name attribute selector to check if a option value is selected but for some reason its not working. Can see why or offer me another solution? I know I could simply use an id on the select tag but I don't want to if theres a jQuery solution.

### jQuery

```
if(jQuery('#beds select[name*="min_beds"] option').val()){
    alert('hi');
}
```

### html

```
<div id="beds">
        <select name="min_beds">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Min Beds</option>
            <option value="1">1 Bed</option>
            <option value="2">2 Bed</option>
            <option value="3">3 Bed</option>
            <option value="4">4 Bed</option>
            <option value="5">5 Bed</option>
            <option value="6">6 Bed</option>
            <option value="7">7 Bed</option>
            <option value="8">8 Bed</option>
            <option value="9+">9+ Bed</option>
        </select>
        <p>to</p>
        <select name="max_beds">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Max Beds</option>
            <option value="1">1 Bed</option>
            <option value="2">2 Bed</option>
            <option value="3">3 Bed</option>
            <option value="4">4 Bed</option>
            <option value="5">5 Bed</option>
            <option value="6">6 Bed</option>
            <option value="7">7 Bed</option>
            <option value="8">8 Bed</option>
            <option value="9+">9+ Bed</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: try something like `if(jQuery('#beds select[name*="min_beds"]').val() != null){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the element's name matches exactly, there is no need to use a modifier. Instead, use `option:selected`:

```js
$('#beds').on('change', function() {
  if( $('#beds select[name="min_beds"] option:selected').val() ){
      alert('hi');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="beds">
        <select name="min_beds">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Min Beds</option>
            <option value="1">1 Bed</option>
            <option value="2">2 Bed</option>
            <option value="3">3 Bed</option>
            <option value="4">4 Bed</option>
            <option value="5">5 Bed</option>
            <option value="6">6 Bed</option>
            <option value="7">7 Bed</option>
            <option value="8">8 Bed</option>
            <option value="9+">9+ Bed</option>
        </select>
        <p>to</p>
        <select name="max_beds">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Max Beds</option>
            <option value="1">1 Bed</option>
            <option value="2">2 Bed</option>
            <option value="3">3 Bed</option>
            <option value="4">4 Bed</option>
            <option value="5">5 Bed</option>
            <option value="6">6 Bed</option>
            <option value="7">7 Bed</option>
            <option value="8">8 Bed</option>
            <option value="9+">9+ Bed</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw code with the modifier on tutorial and assumed it was the standard syntax. I will accept this answer when the option becomes available

Answer (score 1):

Actually your selector is correct but the condition is wrong, to check if there's an `option` selected you can use this code:

```
if (jQuery('#beds select[name*="min_beds"]').val() !== null) {
  console.log("selected");
} else {
  console.log("not selected");
}
```

**Note:**

Of course, you need to attach this code in the `change` event handler of your `select` to reflect changes.

**Demo:**

```js
if (jQuery('#beds select[name*="min_beds"]').val() !== null) {
  console.log("selected");
} else {
  console.log("not selected");
}

jQuery('#beds select[name*="min_beds"]').change(function() {

  if (jQuery(this).val() !== null) {
    console.log("selected");
  } else {
    console.log("not selected");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="beds">
  <select name="min_beds">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Min Beds</option>
    <option value="1">1 Bed</option>
    <option value="2">2 Bed</option>
    <option value="3">3 Bed</option>
    <option value="4">4 Bed</option>
    <option value="5">5 Bed</option>
    <option value="6">6 Bed</option>
    <option value="7">7 Bed</option>
    <option value="8">8 Bed</option>
    <option value="9+">9+ Bed</option>
  </select>
  <p>to</p>
  <select name="max_beds">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Max Beds</option>
    <option value="1">1 Bed</option>
    <option value="2">2 Bed</option>
    <option value="3">3 Bed</option>
    <option value="4">4 Bed</option>
    <option value="5">5 Bed</option>
    <option value="6">6 Bed</option>
    <option value="7">7 Bed</option>
    <option value="8">8 Bed</option>
    <option value="9+">9+ Bed</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need bind [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event with your drop down

```js
$('#beds').change(function() {
    if ($('select[name="min_beds"] option:selected').val()) {
        alert('hi');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="beds">
   <select name="min_beds">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Min Beds</option>
      <option value="1">1 Bed</option>
      <option value="2">2 Bed</option>
      <option value="3">3 Bed</option>
      <option value="4">4 Bed</option>
      <option value="5">5 Bed</option>
      <option value="6">6 Bed</option>
      <option value="7">7 Bed</option>
      <option value="8">8 Bed</option>
      <option value="9+">9+ Bed</option>
   </select>
   <p>to</p>
   <select name="max_beds">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Max Beds</option>
      <option value="1">1 Bed</option>
      <option value="2">2 Bed</option>
      <option value="3">3 Bed</option>
      <option value="4">4 Bed</option>
      <option value="5">5 Bed</option>
      <option value="6">6 Bed</option>
      <option value="7">7 Bed</option>
      <option value="8">8 Bed</option>
      <option value="9+">9+ Bed</option>
   </select>
</div>
```